# MySQL bind variables to PHP - timestamp precision lost

Tags: php, mysql

My MySQL table has a `timestamp(6)` column called `rowid`.  I fetch the data with some SQL which has bind-variables matched to some PHP variables.  The SQL simply looks like this:

```
SELECT k_col1, k_col2, col_data, rowid
FROM   my_table
WHERE  k_col1 = :key1
  AND  k_col2 = :key2;
```

**Question:** Although the `rowid` column stores data at a precision of 6 decimal places, (visible when executing the same SQL directly on the database), when I echo this `rowid` column value back to the browser, it only gives me a precision of 1 second.

Is this just a display/rounding error that can be fixed easily, or is it the actual value that is stored in PHP?  How do I preserve the micro-second precision in my PHP variable?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the PHP `precision` value is set to `14` by default.

The number of seconds since 1970 is currently `1415824454`, which is 10-digits long.  Therefore, I see only 4 decimal places in my floating-point digits.

I change it to 20, and things are better.